# docker-compose mysql 8.0 gives "ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'"

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I've created a mysql:8.0 running container through docker-compose. My backend service, also created in docker-compose, is able to connect without a problem. If I keep the port at 3306 instead of changing it to 3310 there's no issue connecting through CLI. But if I keep it at 3310, when I try to connect to mysql through CLI to make sure that everything is being saved correctly within the mysql container, I get:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

If I first enter the running container in interactive mode, I can then connect to mysql through the command line.

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3310:3306
    expose:
      - 3310
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3310
    volumes:
      - ./backend/scripts/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  backend:
    build: "./messaging-service"
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysqldb
      MYSQL_PORT: 3310
    links:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
```

And I'm trying to connect by using:

```
mysql --host=localhost -P 3310 -uroot -p --protocol=TCP
```

Running docker container ls shows:

```
91c00e485c2a   mysql:8.0            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes (healthy)   3310/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3310->3306/tcp   chat-api-mysqldb-1
```

What am I doing wrong?
The issue connecting through CLI only happens if I change the port to 3310 in docker-compose.